# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: _GwtInternal_groovy$_run_closure5_closure32_closure33

Tags: grails, gwt

I am currently new to GWT and is in the process of trying it out. I am able to set everything up nicely until the point when I try to create a page using the command: create-gwt-page. Would appreciate help from any of you who had encounter similar problem and solved it. Below is the error:

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: _GwtInternal_groovy$_run_closure5_closure32_closure33
Error |
    at _GwtInternal_groovy$_run_closure5_closure32.doCall(_GwtInternal_groovy:344)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:439)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1379)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1372)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$149.invoke(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
Error |
    at _GwtInternal_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GwtInternal_groovy:324)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor130.invoke(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:166)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor129.invoke(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1152)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:807)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1272)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1166)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor120.invoke(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:166)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor119.invoke(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1253)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1209)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:807)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.Script.invokeMethod(Script.java:78)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1272)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1166)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:137)
Error |
    at _Events$_run_closure4.doCall(_Events.groovy:24)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsBuildEventListener.triggerEvent(GrailsBuildEventListener.java:225)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsBuildEventListener.triggerEvent(GrailsBuildEventListener.java:207)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsBuildEventListener$triggerEvent$0.call(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.creation.GrailsProjectCleaner.clean(GrailsProjectCleaner.groovy:84)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.creation.GrailsProjectCleaner.clean(GrailsProjectCleaner.groovy)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.creation.GrailsProjectCleaner.cleanAll(GrailsProjectCleaner.groovy:60)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.creation.GrailsProjectCleaner$cleanAll.call(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at _GrailsClean$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsClean.groovy:37)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor130.invoke(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:166)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor129.invoke(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1152)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:807)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1272)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1166)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor120.invoke(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:166)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor119.invoke(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
Error |
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
Error |
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:166)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
Error |
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
Error |
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
Error |
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
Error |
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
Error |
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
Error |
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:809)
Error |
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:166)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:61)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
Error |
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeWithGantInstance(GrailsScriptRunner.java:781)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptFile(GrailsScriptRunner.java:573)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptWithCaching(GrailsScriptRunner.java:472)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptWithCaching(GrailsScriptRunner.java:423)
Error |
    at org.grails.ide.api.impl.GrailsConnectorImpl.executeCommand(GrailsConnectorImpl.java:160)
Error |
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.process.GrailsProcess.run(GrailsProcess.java:130)
Error |
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.process.GrailsProcess.main(GrailsProcess.java:93)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:236)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:264)
```

Additional Info:
I am currently using Grails 2.4.4

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for creating page is

```
  grails create-gwt-page <page> <module>
```

Specify the GWT module the page should host.